# Convexity of Norm of Max

Tags: convex-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $p \ge 1$. Show the convexity of the function $h:\mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as:

$$h(\textbf{z})=\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^k \max\{z_i,0\}^p \right)^{1/p}$$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: I was going along this train of thought: 1)Max is convex 2)convex to a power larger than 1 is convex, 3)sum of convex is convex. I got stuck at the last part, where you raise to a power between 0 and 1.

Comment: @ved: The map $x\mapsto x^{p}$, where $0<p<1$, is concave, having negative second derivative on $(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: @Matt: Yes thats why I got stuck.

Comment: To get around the concavity of $(\cdot)^{1/p}$, the trick is to consider $(\sum x_i^p)^{1/p}$ as one thing instead.  The convexity of this kind of function is the subject of [Minkowski's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality).

Answer (score 1):

Consider whether, for a given $i$, $z_{i}$ and $w_{i}$ have the same or different sign. If they're the same, then it is trivial that
$$\max\left\{\lambda z_{i}+(1-\lambda)w_{i},0\right\}=\lambda\max\left\{z_{i},0\right\}+(1-\lambda)\max\left\{w_{i},0\right\}$$
for all $\lambda\in[0,1]$. If they're different, then consider the inequality between $\lambda z_{i}$ and $(1-\lambda)w_{i}$.

To complete the proof, you might consider using the triangle property of a norm.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the "consider the inequality between..." part?